# can't read and write xlsx file php

Tags: php, phpexcel

this is my code i want to attach this file and send it and the values are numerical variables that in excel file i use them to drow a chart 
it dosen't work at all ,
my boss is mad at me , Help

let me explain more . i have to attach an excel file {which contains  4 numbers that are a test result and draw a chart } I've done the test i have the result, i have done sending with attachment but i can't make the file .

```
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$fileType = 'Excel2007';
$fileName = 'Result.xlsx';

// Read the file
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);

// Change the file
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $fileType);

$objSheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

 objSheet->getCell('A2')->setValue($SumY );
  objSheet->getCell('B2')->setValue($SumR );
 objSheet->getCell('C2')->setValue($SumB );
  objSheet->getCell('D2')->setValue($SumG );



// Write the file
$objWriter->save('Result.xlsx');
```

Comment: I can't even see where you're defining `$SumY`, `$SumR`, `$SumB` and `$SumG`. What is it exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: Define "doesn't work at all". Are the values being written to the saved file? Is there a chart defined in your file (if so, why aren't you specifying setIncludeCharts(TRUE) to the reader and writer?) Have you looked at the PHPExcel examples in the /Tests directory?

Comment: Does the user running PHP have write access?

Comment: yes i did , i'm new in this case and confused

Comment: which sample can help me more

Comment: I'd suggest looking at /Tests/34chartupdate.php as the closest to what you're trying to do, and consider pulling the latest github develop branch for more stable chart handling code than the 1.7.7 release

Answer (score 0):

Tell PHPExcel that you want to include charts when reading and writing

Assuming that the chart is defined in your template

```
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php'; 

$fileType = 'Excel2007'; 
$fileName = 'Result.xlsx'; 

// Read the file (including chart template)
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType); 
$objReader->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName); 

// Change the file 
$objSheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 

$objSheet->getCell('A2')->setValue($SumY ); 
$objSheet->getCell('B2')->setValue($SumR ); 
$objSheet->getCell('C2')->setValue($SumB ); 
$objSheet->getCell('D2')->setValue($SumG ); 

// Write the file (including chart)
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $fileType); 
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objWriter->save('Result.xlsx');
```

If the chart isn't defined in your template, then you need to create it in your code

Comment: thanks for help but still just shows a white page ( no action ). please help i really need the code. i can mail the whole code and result file if necessary

Comment: Does the worksheet contain anything at all? Raise this on the PHPExcel discussion board, and post files to http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/10749?ProjectName=phpexcel

Comment: I got it the problem is loading the file

Comment: reading and writing with these codes are impossible even samples doesn't work . i hope to find chart sample code to let the user download the file

Comment: As I said in a comment to your original question: "consider pulling the latest github develop branch for more stable chart handling code than the 1.7.7 release". You should find that the examples in the /Tests directory work perfectly adequately, including the example for updating a template containing a chart

Comment: If you find any examples that don't work.... then explain what errors they give, or what doesn't work... "IT DOESN'T WORK" is useless to solve any problem